# Declaring object classes in C?

Tags: c, object-oriented-analysis

I declared a few geometric figures types such as:

```c
typedef struct s_sphere{
    t_tuple origin;
    double  radius;
} t_sphere;

typedef struct s_cylinder{
    t_tuple origin;
    double  height;
    double  radius;
} t_cylinder;

typedef struct s_triangle{
    t_tuple A;
    t_tuple B;
    t_tuple C;
} t_triangle;

etc...
```

Now, I would like to declare an intersection type which will contain two doubles and a geometric figure. I will then store all my intersections in a chained list:

```c
// I do not know what type to give to geometric_figure
typedef struct  s_intersection{
    double       t1;
    double       t2;
//  what_type    geometric_figure;
} t_intersection;

typedef struct  s_intersection_list{
    t_intersection              intersection;
    struct s_intersection_list  *next;
} t_intersection_list;
```

I could use `void* geometric_figure` but I would like to avoid the most mallocs possible.
Is there a handy way of getting where I want without allocating geometric_object ?

Comment: You may use a [`union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> type which will contain two doubles and a geometric figure.

Consider `union` with an identifier.

```
typedef struct  s_intersection{
  double       t1;
  double       t2;
  int id;  // some id to know what type follows
  union {
    t_sphere sph;
    t_cylinder cyl;
    t_triangle tri;
  } u;
} t_intersection;
```

If `t_intersection` is to be allocated, consider a [flexible member array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) to right size the allocation.

```
typedef struct  s_intersection{
  double       t1;
  double       t2;
  int id;  // some id to know what type follows
  union {
    t_sphere sph;
    t_cylinder cyl;
    t_triangle tri;
  } u[];   // FAM
} t_intersection;
```

Example: allocate a triangle.

```
t_intersection *p = malloc(sizeof *p + sizeof p->u[0].tri);
```

Comment: The FMA part is very interesting. To be sure I get it right, its purpose is to allocate the exact right size to a t_intersection variable ? Like if I chose to not use FAM, a t_intersection variable would always have a size of ``` 2*doubles + int + max_size(union types) = 2*8 + 4 + 3*4*8 = 116 bytes``` (because t_tuples contain 4 doubles so max_size(union types) = sizeof (t_triangle)).  
Whereas if I use an FAM, it will have a size of ``` 2*doubles + int + sizeof(chosen figure) = 2*8 + 4 + chosen types = 20 + sizeof (chosen figure) bytes```. Am I right ?

Comment: @BobDeTunis Yes, almost.  The size of a `struct` includes potential padding in both cases.  With a FAM, `sizeof *p` includes all prior members and padding up to the `.u` member.

Comment: In the link you provided, it is written "The sizeof operator on such a struct gives the size of the structure as if the flexible array member were empty. This may include padding added to accommodate the flexible member; the compiler is also free to re-use such padding as part of the array itself." So won't the struct padding be re-used by the FMA making my calculations correct ?

Comment: Compared to the non-FAM version, is the only con of the FAM version to require allocations or there are others ?

Comment: @BobDeTunis Say the first member of a new figure was `complex long double` with an alignment of 32 requirement.  Then the expected size of `t_intersection` (no FAM) is 8 + 8 + 4 + (32-(8+8+4)) + max_size(figures).  The expected size of `t_intersection` (with FAM) is 8 + 8 + 4 + (32-(8+8+4)).

Comment: @BobDeTunis "the only con of the FAM version to require allocations " --> With a FAM, allocations are not _required_ if the `.u` member is not used - just use `t_intersection p;`.  FMA requires C99 or later and programmers/tools  not stuck in C89.  Perhaps other disadvantages.